# Using fetch data as array in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm using a composable provided by Vuejs.org that looks like this

```
// fetch.js
import { ref, isRef, unref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

export function useFetch(url) {
  const data = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)

  function doFetch() {
    // reset state before fetching..
    data.value = null
    error.value = null
    // unref() unwraps potential refs
    fetch(unref(url))
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => (data.value = json))
      .catch((err) => (error.value = err))
  }

  if (isRef(url)) {
    // setup reactive re-fetch if input URL is a ref
    watchEffect(doFetch)
  } else {
    // otherwise, just fetch once
    // and avoid the overhead of a watcher
    doFetch()
  }

  return { data, error }
}
```

And within the script tag I'm using

```
let loopableValues = ref([])
const { data, error } = useFetch(
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
)
loopableValues.value = data
return { loopableValues }
```

My issue is that the variable "data" is not a pure array that I can loop using something like this in the template:

```
<div v-for="value in loopableValues" :key="value.id"> {{ value.id}}</div>
```

Cause when I run this I get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: value is undefined". So I think I need to handle the promise somehow in order to loop out the data as above, but I'm stuck and don't know how to go forward. Do I need to use a function on the data coming back from the fetch composable or is it something else I'm misssing?

Answer (score 0):

`data` will be a string unless you add `.json()` after `useFetch`.

Once you tell fetch to get json, it will deserialize into an array.